# Detect presence and location of a ball in video with opencv

Tags: opencv, video, object-detection

How to detect position of a moving ball in a video?
Camera position is steady for the duration of the video.

Looking for algorithm or approach. Currently tried:

1. substract frames from each other to find difference. (ball is
   present together with a bunch of other moving parts)
2. Blur, canny, find contours, make convex hulls
3. Assume anything with more than 5 points on the convex is a ball
4. Doesn't work: too many other objects qualify (ie, people moving,
   birds, trees, w/e
5. Ball is not round on video. It's a squashed ellipse in motion
6. Ball movement leaves a trail of 'changed pixels' which are the
   background that's being uncovered
7. Ball is not of a [single color](http://www.canuckstuff.com/store/images/large/volleyballs/vmks300_lrg.jpg) and not always present / visible

Comment: This is quite a common use case with quite a few example on the web - e.g.: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mick. Unfortunately it's all too common to have a single color object. As my ball has no single color, and due to rotation, color pattern is constantly changing. It doesn't even look like a ball, but like a squashed ellipse

Comment: Hi @Alex did you found a solution?